# odoo 9 installed on windows 7, not accessible through intranet network using ip:8069 works fine on installed system

Tags: odoo, intranet, odoo-9, odoo-website

I have installed odoo 9 on a windows 7 machine..

All working well when i try to access like localhost:8069 or 192.168.1.11:8069

But the same dosnt work when i try to access from locally connected computers.. I am trying to access odoo from computers connected through lan..
trying to access 192.168.1.11:8069

However If I try to access Xampp Server using the ip it works well..

when I ping 192.168.1.11:8069 from any network computers it shows 'unknown host'

I am relatively new to this kind of network config thing.. Hope if anyone had similar issue and have sorted it out??

PS. Same thing happens when I install odoo on an Ubuntu 14.04 based computer..

Looking Forward to a solution.

Thanks in Advance.
VJ

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of reasons that can cause this.  What you are describing is a network issue and not a odoo issue.  You cannot ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port number.  I would start with some of the obvious tests:

1. Disable the firewall and anti-virus
2. If it is the firewall, set it up to open port 8069 and make sure that the firewall allows connections from other computers.

Comment: Have tried disabling firewall as well as opened port 8069.. Didnt worked..

Comment: Have given up trying on Odoo.. implemented self developed SaaS based CRM for the company now.. Thanks for the efforts guys..